# Using OrderBy in Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables.  One is called `Round`, which contains two columns called `CompetitionId` and `StartDate` (plus a bunch of other columns unimportant to this question). I also have a table called `Competition` with a column named `Id`. The `Round.CompetitionId` is a foreign key to `Competition.Id` (a one-to-many relation -- one competition could have many rounds).

So when Entity Framework translates these tables to C# classes, it gives me two classes, one `Round` which has a reference to `Competition` and one `Competition` with an `IEnumerable<Round>`.

Now I want to run a Linq query that returns all my competitions ordered by the `StartDate` stored in `Round` table but grouped together by the logical round number as determined by the date. So, for example,  say I have two competitions each with 3 rounds. I want the two first-rounds (plus their competition info) to be returned, followed by the two second-rounds and so on.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
var results = Competitions
    .SelectMany(c =>
        c.Rounds
         .OrderBy(r => r.StartDate)
         .Select((r, i) => new
         {
             RoundNumber = i + 1,
             Round = r,
             Competition = c
         })
    )        
    .OrderBy(r => r.RoundNumber)
    .ThenBy(r => r.Round.StartDate)
    .ThenBy(r => r.Competition.Id)
    .ToList();
```

Then you can enumerate the results like this, for example:

```
foreach (var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:MMM dd, yyyy} - Round {1} of Competition {2}",
                      item.Round.StartDate, item.RoundNumber, item.Competition.Id));
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/U515UK

Comment: tnx for introducing .net fiddle

Comment: Thanks @BrianRogers. Initially the compiler wasnt too happy with the query since I had `var results = _dbContext.Competitions.....` but once I split the code into `var Competitions = _dbContext.Competition.ToList();` and followed that up with your code, it worked like a charm. Thanks again for the help.